# page_size_query_param is throwing error when giving custom pagesize in DRF PageNumberPagination

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have defined custom pagination as follows

```
class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):


    page_size_query_param='size'
    max_page_size = 100
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'links': {
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            },
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'page_size': self.page_size,
            'results': data
        })
```

And in the views I imported this pagination class as follows

```
class LeadViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        customer = get_customer_for_client_user(user)
        myDict = dict(self.request.query_params)
        ----
         # some code
        ----
        return queryset
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
    serializer_class = LeadsSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

And my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'lead.pagination.CustomPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

My query is as follows

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/leads/?size=5 "Authorization: Bearer xxxxx"
```

But Im getting error

```
FieldError at /leads/
Cannot resolve keyword 'size' into field. Choices are: Call_Optout, Company_Name, Date, Description, Email,etc ...
```

Comment: Probably you are passing the `myDict` variable to a **`.filter()`** method of Queryset

Comment: Yes because I have filtering also need to be done from the client side

Comment: Just try **`myDict.pop('size', None)`**

Comment: Yes now it's not throwing error, but page size is 10 @ArakkalAbu instead of 5